# Variable Number of Features According to Dimensions in CATIA

Tags: catia

I have worked with CATIA vba coding, and I know that it is possible to generate geometrical features (like planes, points, intersections, ...) using a vba code. And also I know that you can repeat an operation (for example creating a planes) as many number as required in the vba. But the problem is that the vba is actually offline, I mean you should execute the code to generate the features every time.

In my case, I am creating a part template in which not only the dimensions are parametric, but also the number of geometrical features are also related to the input parameters. For example, when I set a length parameter to 100mm, 2 planes should be created; and when I change it to 200mm, 2 additional planes should be defined. And if I change it back to 100mm, 2 planes only should be remained. This means the number of planes in addition to their locations are related to the input parameter.

Is there any feature in CATIA that can do such thing? I guess there should be something related in the "knowledgeware" workbench, but I couldn't find the right thing.

Comment: The "Knowledge Pattern" is a special kind of Rule which will do what you ask in a part. It is available in the PKT workbench when working in a part.

Comment: @CRJohnson Thank you for your answer. It seems that the "Knowledge Pattern" is exactly what I need. I would like to mark your answer as accepted, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Knowledge Pattern" is a special kind of Rule which will do what you ask in a part. It is available in the PKT workbench when working in a part